# Echo variables and appending text inside a loop

Tags: bash, loops, echo

I'm trying to read from a file line-by-line and add text to every line, before echo-ing them.

But the output always looks wrong

link.txt contains (with a newline at the end):

```
http://example.com/ddk.zip
http://example.com/453.zip
http://example.com/hth.zip
```

```
test=1; while read link; do echo "so $link wow $test"; done < link.txt
 wow 1p://example.com/ddk.zip
 wow 1p://example.com/453.zip
 wow 1p://example.com/hth.zip
```

Strangely, it works fine outside a loop:

```
test=1; link=2; echo "so $link wow $test"
so 2 wow 1
```

I need it in a single-line format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when your file has DOS line endings (`\r\n`). Fix it using following command and your script will work:

```
dos2unix link.txt
```

Or add `\r` to `IFS` if you don't want to modify `link.txt`:

```
test=1
while IFS+=$'\r' read -r link; do
  echo "so $link wow $test"
done < link.txt
```